# A PHP selection based on forms

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay..so i want to achieve the following task : 
Say i have 3 tabs (= 3 categories) from each category i have to select one option and then submit the entire thing.Also the options are not radio buttons , they have to be div with specific styles. Please tell me the best optimised way to achieve this. I will be using Bootstrap for styling so tabbing is not a prpblem , the problem is in selecting one  div from each category, and disabling the other divs in the same category . I want to submit the form only when one and only one item has been selected from each category.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this, where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden Ratio for your option .. and use trigger click in JavaScript

```
$('.option_one_div').click(function(){
     $('.option_one_Ratio').trigger('click');
  });
```

and then check for Ratio checked in your form when submit

Comment: Read the question more carefully, the OP said they are not using radio buttons: "*Also the options are not radio buttons , they have to be div with specific styles.*"

Comment: I assumed that he don want to use Ratio just for his website design proposal .anyway Thanks  @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: Thanks this will do for me i guess..